# Android PHP - get array key values

Tags: php, android

I created a JSON string/object/array in android and passed it to PHP.

PHP code snippet with the following results:

```
if(isset($_POST['finalobject']))
{
    $finalobject = $_POST['finalobject'];
    error_log("\n ###### finalobjectpost: " . $finalobject ,3,"android_post_array.log");
}
```

finalobjectpost result:

```
{"myarray":[{"id":0,"name":0,"year":0,"curriculum":0,"birthday":0},{"id":1,"name":1,"year":1,"curriculum":1,"birthday":1}]}
```

I need a foreach loop to display the key header, i.e ID, NAME,Year etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use `json_decode()` function to make json string to array, then use `foreach` loop to do something you want

Comment: i have used the decode and foreach and still can't get the key value for he above final object.